# Python Turtle Graphics dont response, Run with spyder of anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

```
import turtle

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    luis = turtle.Turtle()

    make_square(luis)

    turtle.mainloop()

def make_square(luis):
    turn = 0
    lenght = input('Insert lenght: ')
    lenght = int(lenght)

    while turn < 3:
        turn = input('Insert number of sides of your figure: ')
        turn = int(turn)
        if turn <  3:
            print('The minimum number of sides is 3')

    angle = 360/turn

    for i in range(turn):
        luis.forward(lenght)
        luis.left(angle)

        turtle.done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I try to run in anaconda spyder, but when emerge the window of turtle graphics, it takes a long time to draw or it does not draw.

Comment: `turtle.mainloop()` and `turtle.done()` are synonyms.  You only need call one of them, *once*, as the last thing your program does before turning control over to tkinter.  Keep your `turtle.mainloop()` call in `main()` and toss your `turtle.done()` call in `make_square()`

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have an indentation error there.

You call

> turtle.done()

within your loop that should draw the n-tangle.

If you move the `turtle.done()` outside that loop and run your program again, it draws the n-tangle completely.
Reason for that is that `turtle.done()` will pause the program and you'd need to to close the window in order to continue.

It should then look like that:

```
import turtle

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    luis = turtle.Turtle()

    make_square(luis)

    turtle.mainloop()

def make_square(luis):
    turn = 0
    lenght = input('Insert lenght: ')
    lenght = int(lenght)

    while turn < 3:
        turn = input('Insert number of sides of your figure: ')
        turn = int(turn)
        if turn <  3:
            print('The minimum number of sides is 3')

    angle = 360/turn

    for i in range(turn):
        luis.forward(lenght)
        luis.left(angle)

    #turtle.done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A more interesting variant is the following. Additionally you should always avoid getting command-line input without exception handling because you cannot be sure the user enters something irregular ...

```
import random
import turtle

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    luis = turtle.Turtle()

    make_square(luis)

    turtle.mainloop()

def make_square(luis):


    turn = 0
    length = 0

    while length == 0:
        lengthInput = input('Insert lenght: ')
        try:
            length = int(lengthInput)
        except:
            if turn == 'end':
                return

    luis.pencolor(random.choice(['black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']))

    while turn < 3:
        turn = input('Insert number of sides of your figure: ')
        try:
            turn = int(turn)
        except:

            if turn == 'end':
                return

        if turn <  3:
            print('The minimum number of sides is 3')

    angle = 360/turn

    for i in range(turn):
        luis.forward(length)
        luis.left(angle)


    make_square(luis)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ok, thanks, the code is already running; However when I give the second run of code it does not get to graph and it takes a lot of time and then when I try to close the window it does not respond. Does something similar happen to you?

Comment: What do you mean by second run?

You call make_square with the turtle luis. Then you ask the user for the side length and the number of side. Then you draw whatever thingie the user wants, finish your turtle program (`turtle.done()`) and exit the make_square function. you then enter the turtle.mainloop() which results in the non-termination of your program (screen still shown).

Comment: I edited my answer a bit - could you try to explain what my added code would do?

Comment: @mjoppich, when I run your first code and I close the window, the Spyder shows at console an error message. This error message:

Comment: Indeed, the turtle.done() has been superfluous. I commented that call out.